# Cannot switch between graphics cards on Ubuntu

Tags: gpu, nvidia, ubuntu-16.04

I have recently installed nvidia x server , as mentionned in many posts in order to switch between my graphic cards . However , when I launch the Nvidia X server , there is not Prime tabs allowing me to switch. In face , it's all empty . During the install , it asked me to disable Secure Boot , but I did not comply , as it had lead me to many problems in the past.

So, how can I get my GPUs to show up ?

I am dual booting with Windows 10 , maybe that information helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you have nvidia x server i assume you have the drivers already.
it should come with prime by default. but you can try to install it manualy
do:

sudo apt install nvidia-prime

maybe do a reboot just to make sure.
it should appear in nvidia x server after that

Comment: Did this like 10 times , cleaned everything then reinstalled nvidia x server along with Prime . At the end , I got a black screen so I had to log into command line , to purge nvidia . Seems like there are no issues .